# Which Unix command to get a number from inside this string?

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to hear your suggestions about collecting from this string (which returned by a command) the value which is next to **result** (In this case 15) :

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => 15
}
```

Which utility/command to do suggest me ?
Thanks
Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
command | awk '$1=="\"result\"" {print $3}'
```

Answer (score 4):

`GNU grep`:

```
command | grep -oP '(?<="result" => )\d+'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$1 == "\"result\"" { print $3 }' <<< "$STRING"
```

Comment: +1 for using a here-string but -1 for not quoting the variable